# In Cordova for Windows 8, what is the correct storage option for longterm storage?

Tags: cordova, windows-8, windows-8.1, storage, visual-studio-cordova

I'm building a Cordova app for Windows 8 (surface pro 3) using Visual Studio 2015 RC. My app DB will need to store content such as text, image locations, etc. Of course I want to normalize as much as I can with my DB. Also, I'm working on a web service that the app will use as an API to update the database with new content as needed.

According to [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html) my choices seem to be `localstorage` and `IndexedDB`.

I'm not sure which of these can reliably do what I need or if there is a better solution. I've done some native Android that uses SQLite so I do have some experience there.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that both of those are transient storage.  At the end of that page is: "In addition to the storage APIs listed above, the File API* allows you to cache data on the local file system."  A plugin (which I haven't used) that wraps SQLite is: [here](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage).